# Convert WCF Library Project to WCF Web Service (WCF Application) Project Type

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis

How do I convert WCF Library Project to WCF Web Service (WCF Application) Project Type in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with Geert's answer. Changing that guid would end up having project convert mid way.

Also having your service code in host project is not considered as best practices. As host project should bother only about hosting, means what end point you want expose, What type of security you want... things like that. Not about service's internal implementation.

I would recommend having library/class project as it is and have separate project in same solution to host it. Host project can be anything you want Console, Web Service or Web/WCF Application project.

Answer (score 2):

By changing the projecttypeguid in the project file (csproj file -> unload project and open file).

From :

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

To :

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: Will this have any adverse effects or complications later? like wen deploying / packaging? Also dont we have to rename app.config to web.config? any additional configuration options needed in the web.config file?

Comment: I would not recommend this, in addition to the config file name change you also need a .svc and to rename the service.vb to service.svc.vb and plumb it all up, debugging any errors would be tough.  you are better off recreating the service from scratch, and copying your code in